# Menu conflict on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I have my web hosted on my development environment [here](http://hip-products.rogsiteworks.com/)

If you scroll down past first section you can see that a menu will appear on the right side. Now on desktop that is all fine but on mobile the menu isn't working as intended. It's appearing the same and not on toggle as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdXs2.png)

I am using this code to show and hide menu:

```
var menu = $(".nav");
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var button = $(".shop-top");
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        menu.hide();
        button.hide();
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > windowHeight) {
        menu.slideDown();
        button.slideDown();
    }
});
```

I want the menu to appear as it is on other [pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4whu.png)
Any tip/help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are differences between home navbar html and subpages navbar html, thats where i would look for error :)

Comment: @vicbyte thank you for your input , I understand but that's how I want the menu to look on home navbar , any idea what should I change so I can keep the hide/show menu + it to display on mobile constantly since there's no need to hide/show. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YOUR PROBLEM IS HERE**

```
<ul class="nav " style="right: 4%;
                                    top: 9%;
                                    position: fixed;">
                                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charitable.html">BE CHARITABLE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">HELP</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">CART</a></li>
                                </ul>
```

**SOLUTION IS HERE**

```
<ul class="nav " style="position: relative;">
                                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="charitable.html">BE CHARITABLE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">HELP</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html#">CART</a></li>
                                </ul>
```

**RESPONSIVENESS FOR MENU**
**With JQUERY**

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){

if($(window).width() < 767){
$('.navbar-right > .nav').css({
'position':'relative',
'top':'',
'right':''
});
}else{
$('.navbar-right > .nav').css({
'position':'relative',
'top':'9%',
'right':'4%'
});
}
});
```

**with MEDIA QUERY**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-right > .nav {
   position:fixed !important;
    top:0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
  }
}
.navbar-right > .nav{
 position:fixed;
    top:9%';
    right:4%;
}
```

remove your inline Style

**HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT WORKING**

[Working ScreenShot](https://www.screencast.com/t/PGv0w02RyWDx)

Comment: Thank you but now it appears like this https://i.imgur.com/LF2u9VP.png on desktop 
Should I add media queries for desktop so it appears how I want?

Comment: you want  the solution for mobile screen?

Comment: Well yes that is a solution but now I have issue with desktop view :/ I'll see for a solution..

Comment: no its not problem just put a check if **$(window).width() < 767** than just remove those top and right make the position to relative

Comment: @Nex i got it basically you are showing your menu on scroll  rite?

Comment: yes exactly here how it should look on desktop (just need to align it properly) https://i.imgur.com/B44ecqL.gifv

Comment: hi @Nex please Try this and it will definitely work for you 

**$(window).on('load resize',function(){

if($(window).width() < 767){
$('.navbar-right > .nav').css({
'position':'relative',
'top':'',
'right':''
});
}else{
$('.navbar-right > .nav').css({
'position':'fixed',
'top':'9%',
'right':'4%'
});
}
});**

Comment: also try a media query @Nex   **@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-right > .nav {
    'position':'relative',
'top':'',
'right':''
  }
}**

Comment: Thank you !! Any idea how I can position the 'Shop' menu better in mobile view ? Just add a style to your media queries ?

Comment: yeah Sir @Nex let me try something for you 
 you tried Media Query ?

Comment: @Nex

Put this inside media Query **#brand + button'{
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}**

Comment: @Nex
I just saw you updated changes in your website again your are using inline style   just replace this css inside media query 

.**navbar-right > .nav {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}**